# Connect a DC/DC converter to a virtual precision ground in KiCad

Tags: dc-dc-converter, kicad, virtual-ground

I'm trying to design a circuit which steps up 5V to 12V using a DC/DC converter and then use a virtual precision ground TLE2426 to split the 12v to +/-6V.

I'm using this design in KiCad:

[image]

I'm having trouble with the battery part of my circuit. My DC/DC converter looks like this with 12V at the output:

[image]

I'm then trying to pass the 12V and GND to the TLE2426 for +/-6V

[image]

But looking at the third image, the common pin is tied to ground and -6V. However, KiCad seems to just connect anything else tied to ground to -6V in my PCB schematic. For example, looking at my mounting holes, these are tied to GND in my eeschema but on pcbnew show up as connected to -6V. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: In the third picture, the bottom left GND and the bottom right -6V are the same node (connected by a single green line). Middle right pin 1 is also connected to GND. But pin 1 is only *virtual* ground, right ? It shouldn't be connected to the GND symbol.

Comment: If you designate pin 1 of TLE 4246 as *ground / common*, then the bottom lines in figure two and three should *not* be designated as *ground / common*. They should be marked as -6V. all nodes connected to the triangle symbol are considered the same node (*common*).

Comment: Keep the GNDs separate. One approach would be to label the mid rail AGND (Analog GND) and be rigorous deciding what connects to GND and what to AGND.

Answer (score 1):

The third image shows that pin 1 and 2 of U3 (TLE2426) are effectively connected together. Actually the ERC should tell you that there is a conflict between power pins if the symbols are made correctly. To fix that issue, replace all +12V symbols with +6V and all GND symbols but the one connected to pin 1 of U3 (TLE2426) with -6V. In the end only pin 1 of U3 should be connected to GND for the here shown schematics.